# create NSString in xml format as request to webserver in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, xml, parsing, sudzc

I need to create an `NSString` in xml format, so that I need to send it as a web service request.

I have created the xml structured `NSString` using this code

```
 NSMutableString *res = [NSMutableString string];

 [res appendString:@"<question>"];
 [res appendFormat:@"<productid>%@</productid>", [array objectAtIndex:0]];
 [res appendFormat:@"<questionid>%@</questionid>", [array objectAtIndex:1]];
 [res appendFormat:@"<valueid>%@</valueid>", [array objectAtIndex:2]];
 [res appendFormat:@"<answerText>%@</answerText>", [array objectAtIndex:3]];
 [res appendFormat:@"</question>"];
```

but, when I send this as a request ( web service code created using sudzc) , I got some errors

```
 Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found
 Bad Request
 Error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (CXMLErrorDomain error 1.)
```

this is my sending string

```
 NSString *send=[NSString stringWithString:@"<request><ProductName>ppr</ProductName><questionid>fff</questionid><answerText>%@</answerText></request>"];
```

what all the tags should i replace while creating string xml?

here is my request,,

```
 [service CreateRequest:self action:@selector(CreateRequestHandler:) Email:@"xxxx"  Password:@"anoopgopalan" Token:@"xxx" Request:send];


     - (void) CreateRequestHandler: (id) value {

          // Handle errors
            if([value isKindOfClass:[NSError class]]) {
            NSLog(@"%@", value);
            return;
       }  

          // Handle faults
            if([value isKindOfClass:[SoapFault class]]) {
           NSLog(@"%@", value);
           return;
     }              


                 // Do something with the MFLAPIError* result
             MFLAPIError* result = (MFLAPIError*)value;
                 NSLog(@"CreateRequest returned the value: %@", result);

     }
```

Comment: @vishy i don't know exactly what am missing

Comment: see my answer below.. try with this one..

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some tags in the resulted xml string.. any xml response from web services will be as the below..

Your xml must be embedded with in this..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
//your generated xml with tags
</root>
```

Comment: i tried this also,, but the error exist. i think the error was something related to '<' '\' these tags. :(

Comment: and also, am sending NSString object of xml data

Comment: try by encoding the string and send.. and i didn't get ur request method, whether there is no request url.?

Comment: try by looking some forums relate to sudzc.. or once go through the read me file obtained from sudzc..